How to install the CoinCbc library for Windows?
I would like to solve a mixed integer problem in Rust, using the good_lp crate. As a first step, I want the starting example to run:
use std::error::Error;
use good_lp::{constraint, default_solver, Solution, SolverModel, variables};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    variables! {
        vars:
               a <= 1;
          2 <= b <= 4;
    } // variables can also be added dynamically
    let solution = vars.maximise(10 * (a - b / 5) - b)
        .using(default_solver) // multiple solvers available
        .with(constraint!(a + 2 <= b)[]
        .with(constraint!(1 + a >= 4 - b))
        .solve()?;
    println!("a={}   b={}", solution.value(a), solution.value(b));
    println!("a + b = {}", solution.eval(a + b));
    Ok(())
}

However, to run this example I need to use and link (?) the coincbc library.
How can you make good_lp run in Windows? Can you please give me some sort of a small tutorial that helps me to run it? Or things where I need to pay particular attention to?

You need to download and "install" the coin cbc library, you can download it from their GitHub release page. That however is an involved process, so if you don't need coin cbc then I recommend using another solver that's supported. Looking at that matrix I'd probably choose lp-solvers for the lowest friction

I have also had a look at lp-solvers. However, it also requires that the Cbc solver is installed or some similar solvers, e.g.solve_integer_problem_with_solver(CbcSolver::default()) inside the main function. Which solver is best suited for this? The problem I always have is how to link this solver to the corresponding rust project.

Ah, I didn't see that. Then I'd probably use WSL to have my program compile and run on Linux and use coin cbc, for which installation on Linux is easy
